# Meteor template insertion point

Tags: meteor

Meteor inserts template's contents under `<body>`. Is there a way to make it inserts it somewhere else? E.g. under a `<div class='content'>`

Comment: "somwhere else" = in `<head>`?

Comment: @PeppeL-G I've clarified my question, thanks

Comment: I don't see the problem. Why can't you just do as they have done in the leaderboard example? https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/examples/leaderboard/leaderboard.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

> index.html:

```
<body>
  <h1>Your Site Title</h1>
  <p>Other stuff here</p>
  <div class='content'>
    {{> content}}
  </div>
</body>
```

> content.html:

```
<template name="content">
  Inserted template stuff
</template>
```